# How to reference javascript which is in the parent folder?

Tags: javascript, php, tomcat, iis, web

I have a web applictaion which use has the following folder structure

application_root
js

in the html, I refer the js like

```
<script src="../js/****"></script>
```

everything is file if I start the html page using file:///protocol, but when I use the web server, like http://loclahost:6000/application_root, I found the js cannot be loaded correctly.

How to solve this issue?

Comment: if u have root/index.html and root/script.js - u can just <script type='text/javascript' src="script.js"></script>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to start your path with `/`: `<script src="/js/some.js"></script>`

Anyway, this can be problematic because if you use a virtual directory, `/` won't work since it's the root path.

For example: `/js/some.js` is `http://localhost/js/some.js`, and if your web site is hosted in a virtual directory like `http://localhost/myapp/js/some.js` this approach won't work.

If you find above case part of your issue, you might need to use server-side code to get your application root (i.e. `/myapp/`) so you can concatenate `/myapp/` to `js/some.js` and get the right URI.